# Why can't I take input in neovim shell emulator in c++?

Tags: c++, neovim, terminal-emulator, interactive-shell

I just learned neovim and am planning to switch to neovim but I want to make it more like an ide. I know it's a text editor but it has a built-in shell emulator which is cool for seeing code output. but it's not interactive.
My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Enter name:";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Hello " << name << endl;                       
    return 0;
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3xPD.jpg)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5S6F.jpg)

But I can't give input to the program i wrote.
Now i want to know if there's any way to make the output interactive.

Edit: problem kinda solved. setting up neovim for c++ in termux is a pain in the a55 so I'm using cppdroid

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_terminal_emulator.html)

Comment: yes but I don't see how to take input without entering insert mode. is there any plugin to do so?

Comment: why don't you want to enter insert mode?

Comment: it's not that I don't want to. it's just too much work(I'm really lazy ). I mapped Ctrl-c to compile the code and run it and it runs it in a new terminal where to input stuff i have to press i/a.